# Save worksheet in CSV format to specific to path - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I trying to copy the used range of `Sheet2` and save it in `CSV` format to a specific location. I manage to do so but when i save it, the name of the worksheet in the current workbook which was `Sheet2` change to the name i want to save the CSV. any idea?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

   .UsedRange.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Var2 & "_" & Loc2 & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

When saving csv files in excel, the sheet name always changes to the name of the file by default.